# How to decrease WPF chart column series width at runtime data binding?

Tags: wpf, charts, data-visualization

I've a column series chart and at runtime i'm binding my chart with data from server continuously, the problem is some times i'm getting bars having to much width i don't no why it happens some times only so any one help me how can i reduce my column series chart width irrespective of data coming from server i want to show equal width every time getting data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuppyyy I got solution my self by giving width to bars in styling, it's working.

Comment: For this to be useful for others, could you provide the styling code?